# Unable to smoothly animate the icons on map when coordinates changes using mapbox-gl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, mapbox-gl

this is my react map component:

```
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';
import './switcher/switcher.css';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import React, { useRef, useLayoutEffect, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { deviceCategories } from '../common/deviceCategories';
import { loadIcon, loadImage } from './mapUtil';
import { styleCarto} from './mapStyles';
import { useAttributePreference } from '../common/preferences';

const element = document.createElement('div');
element.style.width = '100%';
element.style.height = '100%';

export const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: element,
  style: styleCarto(),
  center: [80.379370, 23.846870],
  zoom: 4.8
});

let ready = false;
const readyListeners = new Set();

const addReadyListener = listener => {
  readyListeners.add(listener);
  listener(ready);
};

const removeReadyListener = listener => {
  readyListeners.delete(listener);
};

const updateReadyValue = value => {
  ready = value;
  readyListeners.forEach(listener => listener(value));
};

const initMap = async () => {
  const background = await loadImage('images/background.svg');
  await Promise.all(deviceCategories.map(async category => {
    if (!map.hasImage(category)) {
      const imageData = await loadIcon(category, background, `images/icon/car.png`);
      map.addImage(category, imageData, { pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio });
    }
  }));
  updateReadyValue(true);
};

map.on('load', initMap);

map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl({
  showCompass: false,
}));


const Map = ({ children }) => {
  const containerEl = useRef(null);

  const [mapReady, setMapReady] = useState(false);

  const mapboxAccessToken = useAttributePreference('mapboxAccessToken');

  useEffect(() => {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = mapboxAccessToken;
  }, [mapboxAccessToken]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = ready => setMapReady(ready);
    addReadyListener(listener);
    return () => {
      removeReadyListener(listener);
    };
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const currentEl = containerEl.current;
    currentEl.appendChild(element);
    if (map) {
      map.resize();
    }
    return () => {
      currentEl.removeChild(element);
    };
  }, [containerEl]);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} ref={containerEl}>
      {mapReady && children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

I am fetching  coordinates from api endpoint using socket controller, there is redux store that handle the changes in the data, however the position of the icons changes but its not smooth ,i have been trying to make it done since 5 days but i dont find any way how to do it, i am not finding mapbox documentation helpful

Below is the position map component , here the positions are being refreshed and updated to new cordinates, but i want to animate the changes on screen like movement of car on uber/ola app.

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import { Provider, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { map } from './Map';
import store from '../store';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import StatusView from './StatusView';

const PositionsMap = ({ positions }) => {
  const id = 'positions';

  const history = useHistory();
  const devices = useSelector(state => state.devices.items);

  const createFeature = (devices, position) => {
    const device = devices[position.deviceId] || null;
    return {
      deviceId: position.deviceId,
      name: device ? device.name : '',
      category: device && (device.category || 'default'),
    }
  };

  const onMouseEnter = () => map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
  const onMouseLeave = () => map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';

  const onClickCallback = useCallback(event => {
    const feature = event.features[0];
    let coordinates = feature.geometry.coordinates.slice();
    while (Math.abs(event.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
      coordinates[0] += event.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
    }

    const placeholder = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <StatusView deviceId={feature.properties.deviceId} onShowDetails={positionId => history.push(`/position/${positionId}`)} />
      </Provider>,
      placeholder
    );

    new mapboxgl.Popup({
      offset: 20,
      anchor: 'bottom-left',
      closeButton: false,
      className: 'popup'
    })
      .setDOMContent(placeholder)
      .setLngLat(coordinates)
      .addTo(map);
  }, [history]);

  useEffect(() => {
    map.addSource(id, {
      'type': 'geojson',
      'data': {
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
        features: [],
      }
    });
    map.addLayer({
      'id': id,
      'type': 'symbol',
      'source': id,
      'layout': {
        'icon-image': '{category}',
        'icon-allow-overlap': true,
        'text-field': '{name}',
        'text-allow-overlap': true,
        'text-anchor': 'bottom',
        'text-offset': [0, -2],
        'text-font': ['Roboto Regular'],
        'text-size': 12,
      }
    });


    map.on('mouseenter', id, onMouseEnter);
    map.on('mouseleave', id, onMouseLeave);
    map.on('click', id, onClickCallback);

    return () => {
      Array.from(map.getContainer().getElementsByClassName('mapboxgl-popup')).forEach(el => el.remove());

      map.off('mouseenter', id, onMouseEnter);
      map.off('mouseleave', id, onMouseLeave);
      map.off('click', id, onClickCallback);

      map.removeLayer(id);
      map.removeSource(id);
    };
  }, [onClickCallback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    
      map.getSource(id).setData({
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
        features: positions.map(position => ({
          type: 'Feature',
          geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [position.longitude, position.latitude]
          },
          properties: createFeature(devices, position),
        }))
      });
    
  }, [devices, positions]);

  return null;
}

export default PositionsMap;
```

can any body help on thin to figure what i have been missing

Comment: It's not possible for me to run your code and see what it looks like because there are missing imports which are probably not related to the issue.  Please edit your problem to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You want some specific file which prevents you from running the code??